# Updating a column after expiration of specific time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger, event-notification

1. I have a table where I have a column named `state(int(2))` and `modify_time` (`time_stamp` on update current timestamp).
2. I have an update trigger which changes the value of state column to `0` based on some condition.
3. I want to set the value of `state` column to `1` after 24 hours of `modify_time`, if it is still `0`.
4. I tried below method to test :

   ```
   CREATE EVENT myevent1 
    ON SCHEDULE AT current_timestamp + interval 1 minute 
    DO UPDATE test.mytabletable SET state = 0;
   ```

This did not doing anything. Is there any alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable event scheduler.
SELECT @@event_scheduler;  -- check whether event scheduler is ON/OFF
CREATE EVENT e_store_ts  -- create your event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 24 HOURS  -- run every 24 hours
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.youtable set mycolumn='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `UPDATE` query will need some work, because as-written, it will update all of the `state` values to 0 every minute, but if it's not working, you should verify that the event scheduler is actually running.

```
mysql> show variables like 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | OFF   | 
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It shouldn't be OFF.

```
mysql> set global event_scheduler = on;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If it's already on, then check your MySQL error log.  Events that fail to run will log messages there.

Comment: so you mean , for this i can use only Events , not any triggers ? i need to update my state column to 1 after 24 hours of modify_time , if it is 0..